# Set variable kind with "if" or "switch"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to set a variable kind depending of another variable value but I don't know how to do it. I've tried with if and switch but both creates a local variables without change the other (is how it should work).

I've this code:

```
crypto::sha1_t HashKey;

if (CheckCRC == 1){
    crypto::md2_t HashKey;
}
else if (CheckCRC == 2){
    crypto::md4_t HashKey;
}
else if (CheckCRC == 3){
    crypto::md5_t HashKey;
}
```

and this:

```
crypto::sha1_t HashKey;

switch (CheckCRC){
    case 1: {
        crypto::md2_t HashKey;
        HashKey.begin();
    }
    break;
    case 2: {
        crypto::md4_t HashKey;
        HashKey.begin();
    }
    break;
    case 3: {
        crypto::md5_t HashKey;
        HashKey.begin();
    }
    break;
}
```

md2_t, md4_t, md5_t and sha1_t are classes.

At end HashKey is always crypto::sha1_t. Is there any way to change it kind depending of CheckCRC value?

thanks!!

**EDIT:**
i think base class is cryptohash_t and others are definitions:

```
typedef cryptohash_t<CALG_MD2> md2_t;
typedef cryptohash_t<CALG_MD4> md4_t;
typedef cryptohash_t<CALG_MD5> md5_t;
typedef cryptohash_t<CALG_SHA1> sha1_t;
```

Comment: if `sha1_t` is base class of others, you can use `pointer` to base class, and then initialize it with appropriate derived class.

Comment: Is `CheckCRC` a compile time value ?

Comment: CheckCRC is an argument of function. The project is a plugin, and get some variables from main program (lua script based), and CheckCRC is an argument passed from lua script.

Answer (score 2):

The soilution to this problem is to have different types that are of the same baseclass and using `new`.

If we assume your `crypto::sha1_t` is a baseclass, then use `crypto::sha1_t* HashKey;` and:

```
if (CheckCRC == 1){
    HashKey = new crypto::md2_t;
}
else if (CheckCRC == 2){
    HashKey = new crypto::md4_t;
}
else if (CheckCRC == 3){
    HashKey = crypto::md5_t;
}
```

Now you need to generally use `HashKey->` instead of `HashKey.`, and when all is done, `delete HashKey` to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: thanks for reply. I've edited the fist post because i think that base class is cryptohash_t and others are definitions. I'll try with your code and using cryptohash_t instead sha1_t.
Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, the basic principle applies the same, whatever the class is called. However, when there are templates involved, it gets more difficult. Note that `cryptohash_t` in this case is NOT a baseclass as such.

Answer (score 2):

```
crypto::sha1_t *HashKey;

switch (CheckCRC){
    case 1: 
         HashKey = new crypto::md2_t();
         HashKey->begin();
         break;
    case 2: 
         HashKey = new crypto::md4_t();
         HashKey->begin();
         break;
    case 3: 
         HashKey = new crypto::md5_t();
         HashKey->begin();
         break;
}
```

Remember to insert a default action in the switch-case statement in order to avoid weird behaviour of the program for strange input values of CheckCRC!

Comment: Thanks!!, i've to change some code to fit the new "style" :). Later i'll say if it works ;)